# Sufficient conditions for a meromorphic function to be rational

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that rational functions are meromorphic, but under what conditions are meromorphic functions rational? I know that the automorphisms of the Riemann sphere are rational, but are there any more general conditions that ensure rationality?

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! Nice first post. As to you first question, not much comes to mind except rather trivial conditions such as "the function should have finitely many singularities and there should be no essential singularity, not even at $\infty$". As to automorphisms of the Riemann sphere - these are indeed all rational, but they are also very special.

Comment: I think all it has to do is to converge at infinity.  It can converge either to a finite value or to infinity.

Comment: @Hans, can you go into detail as to why having finitely many singularities and no essential singularities does what we need?

Comment: I have a very silly and probably unhelpful characterization in terms of value distribution theory. I'll post it when I get home, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

The given function should have a finite number of poles on the Riemann sphere with the counting done with multiplicity given by the order of the pole.

First consider the complex plane, i.e., the Riemann sphere without the point at infinity. Then by multiplying the meromorphic function, $f(z)$ with an entire function $q(z)=\prod_{a_i\in \text{poles}}(z-a_i)^{m_i}$ that vanishes with suitable multiplicity, $m_i$, at each pole, $a_i$, removes the  meromorphicity in the complex plane. You get an entire function, $p(z)=f(z) q(z)$ with no poles in the complex plane. The order of the pole at infinity is given to be finite. Thus, you need to argue that $p(z)$ is a polynomial in $z$. Then, you have shown that $f(z)=p(z)/q(z)$.